# Has anyone found a better way to test web apps across platforms yet?

Tags: html, testing

What are the current best recommended resources for cross-browser testing in the CSS3 jquery world? I am adopting html5 and have adopted parts of css3 into my latest web project. I have also changed over to jquery for my scripting needs. The [best answer I have seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995866/recommended-crossbrowser-testing-solution) for testing this pre-dates html5 and css3 being ready for primetime.

I am testing in Windows Opera, Safari, 2 Firefoxes+firebug, IE+f12 and  two Androids. I test myself for input=expected output in my javascript and browser-sizing and other rendering issues. I test my php generated code by rendering it in firefox, then validating. I am trying to test for user experience by having myself and other people use the site and reporting on their opinion of the design, usability and overall impressions of the site-in-action. I present them with views on different sized devices. I even am lucky to have a friend with color-blindness;-} The F12 solution is particularly dissatisfying when testing in IE and the css rendering consumes large chunks of my development time.

Is better emulation available? Has anyone found a better (i.e. fast, easy, efficient, scientific) way to test across platforms yet? I am hoping for a strategy like unit-testing to emerge in the online community so we can make our apps more stable and robust as they become more powerful and influential. I can't seem to find a way to tame this chaos!

Answer (score 2):

Have you used Selenium?

http://seleniumhq.org/

It is a tool to automate browser testing. Some people at Google made it and open sourced it.

Comment: I am looking at the Selenium documents now and it looks like a partial solution, especially for the generated markup. However, I don't know how much it can help with the rendering issues. Truthfully though, if my sites rendered as beautifully as their documents I would be pretty happy!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [RIATest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest/features/technologies/htmljavscript.html) for cross-platform cross-browser testing of HTML5 applications.

It works on Windows and Mac, supported browsers are Firefox, IE and Chrome. Automated testing scripts written on one platform/browser can be run against all other supported platforms/browsers.

(Disclaimer: I am a RIATest team member).